# Multiple filters on a collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a CheckBox list that filters my collection of objects by some of it's properties.

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to do the last button, which would filter the list of employees based on it's job description property (string).

For now it looks like this

```
    private void ApplyFilters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> FunctieFilters = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            FunctieFilters.Add(item.ToString());

        }            
    }
```

Which gives me the selected job descriptions in a `list<string>`.

I'd like to sketch what I'm trying to achieve with a mix of code/pseudo-code.

```
public string FilterJobDescription(List<string> descriptions)
    {
        string res = "";
        var queryResult = from w in Werknemerlijst
                          where w.functie == // any of the selected job descriptions
                          orderby w.Naam
                          select w;

        foreach (var w in queryResult)
        {
            res += w.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        res+= Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        return res;
    }
```

What would be the best way to construct this type of filtering?

Answer (score 2):

Your filtering method can build a list of predicates that you will use to filter out the employees:

```
var filters = new List<Func<Employee, bool>>();
```

You then keep adding appropriate conditions if they are valid. So for instance if you filter the employee by name you can check if the name text box has any value. If so add appropriate filter to the list:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameTextBox.Text))
{
    filters.Add(emp => emp.Name == nameTextBox.Text);
}
```

Depending on what are your fields you can keep adding the filters to the list. At the end you apply either all or any filter to filter out the employees:

```
var filteredOutEmployees = employees.Where(e =>
{
    return filters.All(f => f(e));
});
```

The final method can look something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Employee> ApplyFilters()
{
    var filters = new List<Func<Employee, bool>>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameTextBox.Text))
    {
        filters.Add(emp => emp.Name == nameTextBox.Text);
    }

    int age;
    if (int.TryParse(ageTextBox.Text, out age))
    {
        filters.Add(emp => emp.Age > age);
    }

    int id;
    if (int.TryParse(idTextBox.Text, out id))
    {
        filters.Add(emp => emp.Id > id);
    }

    // Use this to find employees that fulfil any condition
    // var filteredOutEmployees = employees.Where(e =>
    // {
    //     return filters.Any(f => f(e));
    // });

    // Use this to select the emplyees that fulfil all the conditions
    var filteredOutEmployees = employees.Where(e =>
    {
        return filters.All(f => f(e));
    });

    return filteredOutEmployees;
}
```

Comment: Your code give the error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0834 A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree `

Comment: Are you executing that in context of entity framework? The code may be to complex for converting that to SQL and executing against a database. But you should be fine when running that on a collection.

Answer (score -2):

This approach requires that you have stored all of the job descriptions in a `List<T>` before hand.

```
Werknemerlijist
    .Where(JobDescriptions.Contains(w.functie))
    .OrderBy(w.Naam)
    .Select(w)
    .ForEach(w =>
        {
             res += w.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        });

return res += Environment.Newline + Environment.NewLine;
```